# Issue with sharing variables between Activities

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

The code is heavily borrowed from https://github.com/hastarin/android-udpsender and where his code is very versatile, I want a simple way to send a udp packet to an Arduino that will unlock a garage door.

Basically page one (MainActivity) has a big "Open" button and a small "Set Params" button. Page two (Main2Activity) is mostly the borrowed code with lots deleted and provides a way to input the IP address, port and the unlock code word. Currently there is "Send" button that sends the assembled udp packet to the client and it works as intended.

The issue is that I really don't want to have to access the second page regularly. I need the "sendData" routine in MainActivity to have access to the stored values for processing.

At this time, pressing the Send button on the MainActivity page results in:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.kke.android.opener.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:47)
    at com.kke.android.opener.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
```

Which I take to mean that the the variable values are not available to the sendData routine on that page.

MainActivity

```
package com.kke.android.opener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    Button btnset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSet);
    btnsend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnset.setOnClickListener(this);
}
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.buttonSend:
             sendData(v);
             break;

         case R.id.buttonSet:
             editParams(view);
             break;
     }
 }


public void sendData(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

   /**Load global variable from Main2Activity*/

   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   String host = bundle.getString("host");
   String port = bundle.getString("port");
   String dataText = bundle.getString("dataText");

    //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    //String host = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!host.matches("\\b(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\\b")) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Invalid IP Address";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
    //String port = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!port.matches("^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d\\d|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|0)$")) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Invalid Port Number";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
   // editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    //String dataText = editText.getText().toString();
    if (dataText.length() < 1 ) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Text required to send";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    String uriString = "udp://" + host + ":" + port + "/";
    uriString += Uri.encode(dataText);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    startActivity(intent);
}

    /** Called when the user taps the Set Params button */

    public void editParams(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Main2Activity

```
package com.kke.android.opener.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.kke.android.opener.R;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
    ToggleButton toggleButton = ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton));
    boolean checked = settings.getBoolean("toggleChecked", false);
    toggleButton.setChecked(checked);
    toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    if (checked) {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
    editText.setText(settings.getString("host", ""), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
    if (checked) {
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
    editText.setText(settings.getString("port", ""), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    editText.setText(settings.getString("dataText", ""), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    /** Set up global variable to pass to MainActivity */

     Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("host", "host");
     intent.putExtra("port", "port");
     intent.putExtra("dataText", "dataText");
     startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Get current values
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    String host = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
    String port = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    String dataText = editText.getText().toString();



    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("host", host);
    editor.putString("port", port);
    editor.putString("dataText", dataText);
    editor.putBoolean("toggleChecked", ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)).isChecked());

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_send:
            this.sendData(null);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void sendData(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    String host = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!host.matches("\\b(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\\b")) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Invalid IP Address";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
    String port = editText.getText().toString();
    if (!port.matches("^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d\\d|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|0)$")) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Invalid Port Number";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    String dataText = editText.getText().toString();
    if (dataText.length() < 1 ) {
        CharSequence text = "Error: Text/Hex required to send";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    String uriString = "udp://" + host + ":" + port + "/";
    uriString += Uri.encode(dataText);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();


    EditText editTextIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    EditText editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
    if (on) {
        editTextIp.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editTextPort.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    } else {
        editTextIp.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        editTextPort.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    }
 }
}
```

All suggestions will be appreciated. 
Please remember I am very new to this.

Comment: It seems to me that you have some serious design issues: 1. Both activities have the same layout. This is completely redundant since you can just have one Activity class and create multiple instances of it. 2. The flow of data between activities seems strange. This is especially true since `MainActivity` can be started both from the Launcher and from `Main2Activity`. You need to step back and figure out the flow of your app before you continue further.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your Activities have the exact same layouts... That is probably confusing...

Anyways, you called `getIntent().getExtras()` when there was no extras to get (that activity just started).

Sample of your code

> ```
>    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>    String host = bundle.getString("host");
>    String port = bundle.getString("port");
>    String dataText = bundle.getString("dataText");
> ```

You can simply do this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
// TODO: declare some variables here
String host, port, text;
if (extras != null) {
    // TODO: assign your variables here
   String host = extras.getString("host");
   String port = extras.getString("port");
   String dataText = extras.getString("dataText");
}
```

However, don't be surprised if you don't get anything because the intent could still be empty

Comment: I think you are right that they will still be empty since I don't want to access the 2nd activity on additional uses if the settings are already there. The original author queries the text views to process the uri string. I can't seem to figure out how the values are persisted and how to read them into the main activity.

Comment: You call `intent.setExtra()` then `startActivity(intent)` followed by `getIntent().getExtras()` in that order. It isn't that hard to figure out with a [mcve]. However, you have a lot of code, so strip it down to the basics.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your MainActivity is probably launched from the Android launcher and not from MainActivity2.

Basically when you click send, you inspect the intent that brought you here (to this activity). Since you came from the launcher, this intent does not have the data that you need to execute the function. Remember that you are setting the data for this intent in your MainActivity2 (on your oncreate method, which is kind of a bad practice in this context).

To fix this, go to the manifest and make your MainActivity2 your launcher activity:

```
<activity android:name="<YOUR_ACTIVITY_TWO_NAME">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will make sure that your Activity2 will be called first, this linking to MainActivity and sending an intent with actual data.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at and maybe have been looking at this wrong. I suspected that the activities had to be used to process but was not sure on exactly how they relate. I spent a good bit of time working out how to make a new main activity screen that would come first.

Comment: just adding the intent filter should fix it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It currently is:                          <activity
            android:name="com.kke.android.opener.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: exactly! Do you have another entry for Main2Activity? If you do (which you should), cut the code that you pasted, the intent filter, remove it from inside MainActivity and paste it inside Main2Activity